# Bash script: Redirect error of command to function that receives an argument

Tags: bash, shell, automation

how can I achieve to redirect the error to a function that receives a string as an argument?

This is the code:

```sh
function error {
    echo "[ERROR]: $1"
}

# This does works:

terraform apply myplan || { echo -e '\n[ERROR]: Terraform apply failed. Fix errors and run the script again!' ; exit 1; }

# Output: [ERROR]: Terraform apply failed. Fix errors and run the script again!



# This does NOT work:

terraform apply myplan || { error 'Terraform apply failed. Fix errors and run the script again!' ; exit 1; }

# Output: [ERROR]
```

I do not understand why.

Comment: Your code is OK with me. In other words, I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: There's no redirection here at all. `||` is a flow-control operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# simulate terraform commands

function terraform_ok {
    echo "this is on stdout from terraform_ok"
    exit 0
}

function terraform_warning {
    echo "this is on stdout from terraform_warning"
    echo "this is on stderr from terraform_warning" >&2
    exit 0
}

function terraform_error {
    echo "this is on stdout from terraform_error"
    echo "this is on stderr from terraform_error" >&2
    echo "this is line two on stderr" >&2
    exit 1
}

function catch_error {
    rv=$?
    if [[ $rv != 0 ]]; then
        echo -e "[ERROR] >>>\n$@\n[ERROR] <<<"
    elif [[ "$@" != "" ]]; then
        echo -e "[WARNING] >>>\n$@\n[WARNING] <<<"
    fi
    # exit subshell with the same exit code the terraform command had
    exit $rv
}

function swap_stdout_and_stderr {
    "$@" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3
}

function perform {
    (catch_error "$(swap_stdout_and_stderr "$@")") 2>&1
}

function die {
    rv=$?
    echo "\"$@\" failed with exit code $rv."
    exit $rv
}

function perform_or_die {
    perform "$@" || die "$@"
}

perform_or_die terraform_ok apply myplan
perform_or_die terraform_warning apply myplan
perform_or_die terraform_error apply myplan

echo "this will never be reached"
```

Output (all on `stdout`):

```
this is on stdout from terraform_ok
this is on stdout from terraform_warning
[WARNING] >>>
this is on stderr from terraform_warning
[WARNING] <<<
this is on stdout from terraform_error
[ERROR] >>>
this is on stderr from terraform_error
this is line two on stderr
[ERROR] <<<
"terraform_error apply myplan" failed with exit code 1.
```

Explanation:

- The swapping of `stdout` and `stderr` (`3>&2 2>&1 1>&3`) is done because when you do `variable=$(command)` the `variable` will get assigned whatever comes on stdout from `command`. The same applies in `catch_error "$(command)"`. Whatever comes on `stdout` from `command` will be assigned to `$@` in the function `catch_error`. In your case you I assume you want to catch what comes on `stderr` instead, hence the swapping.
- The final `2>&1` on the line is done to redirect `stderr` (which is the old `stdout`) back to `stdout` so that the expected behavior of `grep`ing in the output from this script can be done as usual.
- Since the `catch_error ...` command is running in a subshell I've used `||` to execute another command in case the subshell returns an error. That command is `die "$@"` to exit the whole script with the same error code that the command exited with and to be able to show the command that failed.

Comment: Can you please explain the following lines:
echo "this is on stderr from terraform_bad" >&2 -> Why do you redirect stdout to stderr?
error "$(terraform_bad apply myplan 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3)" 2>&1 -> The flow of the redirections. Pretty hard for me to understand.

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy The swapping of stdout and stderr? Ok, I'll try explaining that better. Btw, does it do what you want? If not, please update the question so I can work on making it do what you want.

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy I added an explanation and note that I made a minor update of the script too. I forgot `(` and `)` around the inner command before.

Comment: You solution works really well. I only wonder if it is also possible to use my approach with terraform apply myplan || ... as posted within my question, i.e. to redirect the stderr correctly.

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy No, I don't think you can get that to work that simple. `command1 || command2` will only execute `command2` if `command1` fails, but there's no stream between the commands allowing `command2` to read the output. `command2` will start (_if_ it starts) after `command1` is finished.

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy I had missed a bit and needed to complicate it even more to get all the redirections and exit status working properly. Sorry for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of; this will save all output to a file:

```
terraform apply --auto-approve -no-color -input=false \
    2>&1 | tee /tmp/tf-apply.out
```

I believe the expression `&>` would save only errors to the file.

Comment: `&>` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`. `cmd > out 2>&1` and `cmd &> out` does the same thing.

Comment: To a certain extent you're correct; however, in a script `2>&1` is recommended as `&>` could *potentially* break stuff. Search this page (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput) for "For convenience, Bash also makes yet another form of redirection available to you."

Comment: How am I correct only to a certain extent and not to the full extent? What could  it potentially be breaking? I did not find references to such cases in that link.

Comment: First, `&>` displays nothing to the terminal while processing; `2>&1` is the same output to file but displays it in the terminal while processing. Beyond that, looking under the example from link posted, it says:

"`&>` is the same as `> proud.log 2>&1`, but not portable to BourneShell. *It is not recommended practice*, but you should recognize it if you see it used in someone else's scripts."

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` and I said "_`cmd > out 2>&1` and `cmd &> out` does the same thing_" (which is correct) in response to "_... the expression `&>` would save only errors to the file_" (which is wrong).